# GraphicsView does not name a type

Tags: qt

In qt designer using drag and drop. I had made a grid Layout, added a graphics view and have promoted the graphics view i.e adding a custom widget.
After to my project I added a new class graphicsview and I am trying to add Text in graphicsview.It gives me error related to graphics view in th ui file like
1)It does not name a type
2)graphicsview declared out of scope.
Also, following is the link to my whole code. Please tell me what needs to be done to resolve it.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7977981/

Comment: Hi ! Pay attention that you have two différent QGraphicsView. As you said you drag and drop items with Qt designer, so you have a `ui->graphicsView` widget. You also create a class inherited by QGraphicsView, so it's an other one ! I suggest you to remove to one you drag and drop, keeping only the class you created. To add it to your mainWindow, write in mainWindow class something like `GraphicsView *myView = new GraphicsView(this)`.

Comment: May be, but I have already done everything else using ui. So I need to change everything everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that you promoted your widget to graphicsview, not GraphicsView.

Comment: @user3877872 I will, but the link doesn't work also. It points to the main page of the site.

Comment: The biggest mistage is that you used both ways of applying UI-files simultaneously. You inherited you class from `Ui::MainWindow` and created and instance `ui` of `Ui::MainWindow`. Then sometimes you use `ui->control` to access widgets, sometimes `control`. But they are different objects. You called `ui->setupUi(this)` to create widgets that's why `ui->control` exists. If you have used `setupUi(this)` you would  might call `control->`. So choose one of the ways. The other problems are less important.